# Overriding the class's property swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiviewcontentmode

I want to override the **ContentMode** of the **UIImageView** so I wrote this code but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

```
class AspectFitUIImageView: UIImageView {

    override var contentMode: UIViewContentMode {
        get {
            return .scaleAspectFit
        }

        set {
            // contentMode = contentMode
        }
    }
}
```

Can any one tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the contentMode in awakeFromNib() like so:

```
class AspectFitUIImageView: UIImageView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
       contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    }

}
```

Or if you are not planning on using a Nib or Storyboard, you can use the following:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
}
```

Comment: I can't directly override the properties?